# flyway, use my project directory instead of the 'centralized' flyway directory

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I have a project for which i want to manage the database migrations with [flyway](http://flywaydb.org). The version is 3.1. 
I don't want to put references to this project inside the flyway installation dir, but all database and migration information have to be self-contained in the project directory. 
How can I achieve this? Which folders and configuration files am I supposed to have in my project dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented in Flyway 3.2, to be released this week.

Comment: Ok, I've installed the new 3.2.1 release, but i can't figure out how to manage my flyway files in the project directory. I've created a conf/flyway.properties file in my project directory. Then i've launched (Always from the project directory) "flyway migrate" and i've got the error: "ERROR: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!"

Comment: If the config file is not in the current directory, you must pass it as an argument. See http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#configFile